# parsererror: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc application. I am trying to send a http post request using the below method:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/suggested-events/vote/'+votedEventId,
        success: function(response) { console.log("Hey: "+JSON.parse(response)); },
        
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log("TextStatus: "+textStatus);
           console.log("ErrorThrown: "+errorThrown);
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

the http post request successfully triggers the below rest controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/suggested-events/vote/{votedEventId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> voteForASuggestedEvent(@PathVariable Long votedEventId){
        log.info("You have made a vote for: "+votedEventId);
                HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("responseHeaders", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

But as you see, I am interested to receive, and print the response data in my console:

```
success: function(data) { console.log("Hey: "+data); }
```

The problem is:  **nothing happens in my console**

*I am sure the BackEnd receives the request and provides an answer.*

The below image shows the rest response reaches to the Network inspect in browser console

[image]

But it does not get printed in console

Comment: So add some error handling and also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network

Comment: Yes. Add error handler and inspect ajax request

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's ajax automatically parses the data if contentType is set to application/json, so you don't need to parse here

```
console.log("Hey: "+JSON.parse(response));
```

Replace that with

```
console.log("Hey: "+ response);
```

Apart from that, if you expect JSON, you need to return JSON from your controller...